# Declare dynamic variable in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm currently passing via the context a variable named `image_1`, `image_2`, etc.  I'm unsure how many images there.  So I'm trying to make a for loop to go through the total count and make variables, `{{ image_1 }}`, `{{ image_2 }}`, etc.

But the only thing I can think to try is this, and it's not working.

```
{% for i in 10 %}
   {{ image}}{{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Of course the 10 being another variable I am passing.  So in summary I'm trying to make `{{ image}}{{ i }}` instead be the equivalent of `{{ image_1 }}` via the for loop.

Comment: Why not simply pass a **list** into the context?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat once I read your comment, that made sense and did that.

Comment: I'm curious how you're getting `image_1 ... image_n` in your view. Templates have `{{ forloop.counter }}`. You might also want to pass a `QuerySet` instead of individual images. Can you package all images up as a queryset?

Comment: `image_1` and `image_2` is just a Variable or It is showing Image ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to send it as a list from the views.py through the context dictionary. just concatenate the filename [image as in this case] with each value through the range and append it to the list